# Proof that the area of the union of two adjacent regions is the sum of each regions area?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory

Consider two adjacent regions, particularly in R2 but I would love an answer that generalizes to several dimensions, the sum of the areas of each region is the area of the union of the regions. Im looking for a rigorous proof of this in the context of real analysis/set theory. Thank you

Comment: What is the relevance of the adjacency condition? To me it just looks like this is an immediate consequence of finite additivity, a property that any measure has be definition.

(If you are not using the word "area" in the sense of a measure, what is your definition of area?)

Comment: How are you measuring area? If you are using either Riemann or Lebesgue integration, then the condition of finite additivity (or 2-additivity, if you like) which is imposed on the integral operator is due to the property that integrals can be added. Do you want a proof that integrals can be added, or something like that?